# Are superconducting and normal electrons not interchangeable in the momentum space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, superconductivity

An interesting result in Nature "A superconductor free of quasiparticles for seconds"
https://www.nature.com/articles/s41567-021-01433-7
It shows that superconducting (paired) electrons don't hop into normal (unpaired) states for seconds. The measurement device detects single pair-breaking-events for a large pair population, so the average life time of each pair is much longer than a few seconds (up to many hours). If so, then the superconducting and normal electrons are not interchangeable in the momentum space during the measurement.
More intriguing: all modern theories of superconductivity assume that all conduction electrons (superconducting + normal) are interchangeable in one shared momentum space, i.e. every electron may be awhile superconducting and awhile normal. So it's unclear are superconducting and normal electrons interchangeable or not?